# Cannot autowire 2 Configuration beans of the same type

Tags: spring, annotations

I have two GenericHandlerResolver beans that are defined in HandlerConfiguration.java like:

```
@Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public GenericHandlerResolver defaultHandlerResolver() {
    return new GenericHandlerResolver(){{
        setHandlers(new ArrayList<Handler>(){{
            add(loggingHandler());
            add(sessionHandler());
        }});
    }};
}

@Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public GenericHandlerResolver maskingHandlerResolver() {
    return new GenericHandlerResolver(){{
        setHandlers(new ArrayList<Handler>(){{
            add(maskingLoggingHandler());
            add(sessionHandler());
        }});
    }};
}
```

Then I want to Autowire two different beans into WebServiceConfiguration.java and use them in several dozen JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean beans like:

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration {
...

public Integer paymentServiceTimeout;
@Bean @DependsOn("applicationProperties")
public Map<String, Object> paymentServiceProperties(){
    return new HashMap<String, Object>(){
        {put(timeoutKey, paymentServiceTimeout);}
    };
}

...
// Logging handler resolver:    
/*@Autowired
protected GenericHandlerResolver defaultHandlerResolver;*/

// Logging handler resolver that will mack Credit Cards:
@Autowired
protected GenericHandlerResolver maskingHandlerResolver;

...

@Bean
@Lazy
@DependsOn("applicationProperties")
public JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean paymentServicePort() throws Exception {
    JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean jppfb = new JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean() {{
        setServiceInterface(PaymentServicePortType.class);
        setWsdlDocumentUrl(new URL(paymentServiceEndpoint + "?wsdl"));
        setServiceName("PaymentService");
        setEndpointAddress(paymentServiceEndpoint);
        setCommonProperties(this,
                paymentServiceProperties(),
                maskingHandlerResolver,
                LEGACY_NAMESPACE);
    }};
    jppfb.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jppfb;
}

protected void setCommonProperties(JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean bean,
                                   Map<String, Object> customProperties,
                                   GenericHandlerResolver handlerResolver,
                                   String namespace) {
    bean.setMaintainSession(false);
    bean.setLookupServiceOnStartup(false);
    bean.setCustomProperties(customProperties);
    bean.setHandlerResolver(handlerResolver);
    bean.setNamespaceUri(namespace);
}
```

My issue is that this works in XML config, but now that I move this to javaConfig, if I have more than one GenericHandlerResolver in WebServiceConfiguration.java, the handler does not work (no logging), but I dont get any error messages so I dont know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Resource annotation instead of Autowired:

```
@Resource(name="defaultHandlerResolver")
protected GenericHandlerResolver defaultHandlerResolver;

@Resource(name="maskingHandlerResolver")
protected GenericHandlerResolver maskingHandlerResolver
```

Alternatively you could use @Qualifier with @Autowired

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("defaultHandlerResolver")
protected GenericHandlerResolver defaultHandlerResolver;*/

@Autowired
@Qualifier("maskingHandlerResolver")
protected GenericHandlerResolver maskingHandlerResolver;
```